# Can I mark a field invalid from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

From reading [this post](http://html5doctor.com/css3-pseudo-classes-and-html5-forms/) I have found that there are some pseudo classes for 'valid' and 'invalid' input values introduced to HTML5.

Is there a way I can mark an input field as invalid/valid from javascript? Or alternatively, can I override the validation method used?

Comment: You could always double-up with an "invalid" class, but it'd be really interesting to learn that there's a better way.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You could use the customValidity function for this purpose.

If you add a customValidity message to the field, it becomes invalid. When you set the message as an empty string, it becomes valid again (unless it is invalid because of other reasons).

`field.setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");` will make the field invalid.

`field.setCustomValidity("");` will make the field valid unless it fails an HTML5 constraint.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Added to http://codepen.io/kevinSuttle/post/the-current-state-of-web-forms

Comment: Also, if you want the browser's validity message to show up on `input` or `blur` you can use [field.reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) right after.

Comment: @SamCarlton OMG I was looking for something like this over countless SO Q&As but nobody ever mentioned `reportValidity` to check form without submitting. Thanks a lot, saved my sanity

Comment: Just to add, if you have an invalid-feedback element next to the input element, it will show that message instead.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/guide/html/constraint_validation#complex_constraints_using_the_constraint_validation_api

Comment: Additionally, if you want the validation triggered, but not reported (e.g. by browser tooltips), you can use [`checkValidity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity).

Comment: `invalid-feedback` CSS class is only if you're using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**:
Someone clarified that you're looking for "valid" "invalid" attributes for DOM.

I would add attributes to each tag using `dom_object.setAttribute("isvalid", "true")`. You could also have a central validation function which updates these attributes each time (and use `dom_object.getAttribute("isvalid")` each time).

You could run this function each time an element loses focus, or whenever you want.

Not exactly elegant, but unfortunately there's no "pseudo" support with javascript and HTML5 now.

---

If I understand your question, you can do validation with Javascript. **However, be warned that it is very easy to circumvent client side validation, especially javascript validation**. You should never trust client data and always do checking on the server side.

For example, I could easily find element IDs by inspecting the source code, then do `document.getElementById('some_id').setAttribute('max', new_number)` to change the max value (this was one of the entries from your link).

There are various ways to do it, so I'll try to give you the general idiom.

You can grab the value by doing `document.getElementById('form_element_id').value` (make sure you give the form a `name` which is sent to the server, and an `id` which is used by javascript). For textareas, you can use `.innerHTML`.

Then you have the value in a variable, there are various ways to check it.

For example, you could do `if (parseInt(my_value) < 0) //error`.
You could also use regular expressions, I won't explain it all but you could start here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp . I know w3schools isn't the best source but I find it an okay place to start.

Now for the validation part: add `onsubmit="return validateForm()` to your form tag where validateForm() is the function which does all the checking.  And the function just returns `true` if valid and `false` otherwise. This **overrides the default validation function** (which by default does nothing).

So in the above example, `//error` would be replaced by `return false`. You can do other things too; such as alert the error then return false. You could also use javascript to highlight the invalid fields (not sure if this is what you mean by "**mark an input field as invalid/valid from javascript**")

Of course, if you don't want to check all the fields you only have to return true if the certain ones pass. Again, you shouldn't rely on this, but if you're only out to deter average people then it's an easy solution.

Comment: You're completely correct, but I don't think you understood the question completely. In HTML5, there are various ways of adding attribute values to the HTML markup that imply built-in validation rules. When a browser applies those rules, an input field will match the ":valid" or ":invalid" pseudo-classes in CSS.  Thus, you can write HTML with those attributes, and CSS with ":valid" and ":invalid" selectors with rules, and give visual feedback without any JavaScript at all. The question is whether the ":valid" status is available as a DOM attribute, basically.

Answer (score -19):

> Is there a way I can mark an input field as invalid/valid from
> javascript?

Unfortunately, you can't style pseudo classes in JavaScript, since they're not real elements, they don't exist in the actual DOM.

With vanilla JavaScript you'd use the [validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#Constraint_validation_API_properties).

In jQuery you can simply do this, http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/Kak6S/

```
if ( $input.is(':invalid') ) { ... }
```

> Or alternatively, can I override the validation method used?

If you're using HTML5 validation, then stick to the markup. Otherwise, you can disable HTML5 validation with `$form.attr('novalidate', 'novalidate')` and use JS to validate your fields, and then adding `valid` or `invalid` classes where needed. I made [a plugin](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) that works like this to support non HTML5 browsers.

Comment: What do you mean you can't style them? I'm already doing it. `input:invalid + label::after{content: " INVALID";color: red;}` Adds a red piece of INVALID text after the label which I have next to the input field if the the field is invalid (for example if an email field has an invalid email in it)

Comment: "Is there a way I can mark an input field as invalid/valid from javascript?"
"Unfortunately, you can't style pseudo classes from JavaScript" That's not what the question asked.

Comment: You should be able to use the CSSOM to define a new class with a pseudo-class dynamically though...