# bootstrap 5 form validation is not working for textarea pattern attribute?

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-5

I have used bootstrap 5 form validation method for my forms.  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_form_validation.php

I have tried pattern attribute with input elements

```
<div class="row">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="abc_input" name="abc_input" required="" autocomplete="off" pattern=".*\S+.*">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid input value</div>
    <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
</div>
```

In above sample code, I have attempted for required field and pattern attribute to check "only white space is not allowed". If I skip pattern attribute, then input field allows white space characters to be filled and that's against our required field rule.

The same I have tried to apply for textarea, but pattern attribute is ignored by browser and thus bootstrap 5 validation also not works correctly.

```
<div class="row">
         <textarea class="form-control" id="abc_textarea" name="abc_textarea" required="" autocomplete="off" pattern=".*\S+.*">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid value</div>
        <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
    </div>
```

It will be of great help to me if anyone suggests me to validate textarea.

Comment: I believe textarea cannot be validated using the pattern attribute and needs to be done via JavaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern

Comment: Maybe check out this answer on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777970/can-i-mark-a-field-invalid-from-javascript

Comment: Thanks @Matthew. This hint helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: No problem. If it help solved it (as it was what you needed) maybe promote it to an answer (I think you can) or give a write-up and answer the problem yourself.

Comment: @Matthew: Sure, you can write it as answer and I will mark that as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I found that there is closing `</textarea>` missed in code snippet. Just try below snippet hope will work.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <form method="POST" class="was-validated">
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="abc_input" name="abc_input" required="" autocomplete="off" pattern=".*\S+.*">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid input value</div>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="abc_textarea" name="abc_textarea" required="" autocomplete="off" pattern=".*\S+.*"></textarea>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid value</div>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew has said, TextArea fields can't use the pattern attribute.

Check out Yann Dìnendal's solution here: *(& upvote it if you like it!)*

- Question: [How to validate pattern matching in textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643417/how-to-validate-pattern-matching-in-textarea)

It's probably the closest you'll get.. but!- on the plus: at least it's a generic function you can use elsewhere